# ERROR: Module ndiswrapper not found

Tags: arch-linux, ndiswrappers

Trying to use ndiswrapper on Arch, I got the following error (that is actually the result of the command: `ndiswrapper -l`):

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module ndiswrapper not found.
module version is too old!
utils version: '1.9', utils version needed by module: '0'
module details:
modinfo: ERROR: Module ndiswrapper not found.

You may need to upgrade driver and/or utils to latest versions available at
http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net
```

However, I installed `ndiswrapper-dkms` from the community repository. How can I solve that? I am running on kernel 4.4.1-2.

EDIT: I tried to compiled ndiswrapper from sources, too, but without success. The error I get is the following:

```
ndiswrapper-1.59/driver/crt.c:470:2: error: implicit declaration of 
function ‘net_srandom’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

net_srandom(seed);
^
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how compiling from source failed. If the version in AUR is too old, that might be your only choice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply this pach: [ndiswrapper-patched-3.14](https://github.com/Schwartz/ndiswrapper-patched-3.14)

Run the following command :

```
git clone https://github.com/Schwartz/ndiswrapper-patched-3.14.git
cd ndiswrapper-patched-3.14
make
```

Comment: I still have errors (see [here](http://pastebin.com/MhSp7vN8)): implicit declaration of function '__vmalloc', 'vmalloc' and 'vfree'... =/

Comment: Try this https://github.com/Schwartz/ndiswrapper-patched-3.14/blob/master/INSTALL

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get your point. Do you mean that I should follow the "INSTALL" instructions? I still get the same compilation errors...

Comment: Adding `#include <linux/vmalloc.h>` to "driver/loader.c" moves to another issue: "implicit declaration of function 'strnicmp'".